# Unable to plot two arrows with tikzpicture, possible bug

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows, tikz-path

The following code does not work:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->]
            \node at (1.85,-1.2) (bF) {$F$};
            \node at (1.27,-1.2) (bd) {$d$};
            \node at (3.6,-1.2) (bW) {$W$};
            \node at (1.9,-1.1) (GW) {};
            \node at (1.29,-1.1) (EGxbW) {};
            \node at (2.28,-0.9) (ExbW) {};
            
            \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}, thick]
            (GW) edge[bend right] node [left] {} (EGxbW);
            (bW) edge[bend right] node [left] {} (ExbW);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It produces the following image:

[image]

Where as if we change the last two lines of code (or if we consider the dependent lines of code independently) we get:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->]
            \node at (1.85,-1.2) (bF) {$F$};
            \node at (1.27,-1.2) (bd) {$d$};
            \node at (3.6,-1.2) (bW) {$W$};
            \node at (1.9,-1.1) (GW) {};
            \node at (1.29,-1.1) (EGxbW) {};
            \node at (2.28,-0.9) (ExbW) {};
            
            \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}, thick]
            (GW) edge[bend right] node [left] {} (EGxbW);
            (bW) edge[bend right] node [left] {} (ExbW);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and we get:

[image]

It should be possible to make both arrows visible since I have done something similar with the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->]
        \draw[black, very thick] (0,0) rectangle (1.5,1);
        \node at (1.8,0) (aL) {$\overline{L}$};
        \draw[black, very thick] (0.8,-1.7) rectangle (2.3,-0.7);
        \node at (2.55,-1.75) (bL) {$L$};
        \node at (1.05,0.5) (aF) {$\overline{F}$};
        \node at (0.47,0.5) (ad) {$\tilde{d}$};
        \node at (1.85,-1.2) (bF) {$F$};
        \node at (1.27,-1.2) (bd) {$d$};
        \node at (2.8,0.5) (aW) {$\overline{W}$};
        \node at (3.6,-1.2) (bW) {$W$};
        \node at (1.48,0.8) (ExaW) {};
        \node at (2.28,-0.9) (ExbW) {};
        
        \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}, thick]
        (ad) edge [out=230, in=173] (bd)
        (aW) edge[bend right] node [left] {} (ExaW)
        (bW) edge[bend right] node [left] {} (ExbW);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

That generates the following image:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Or is it just a bug in TikZ?

Comment: The surprising thing is that it worked in the third MWE.  The rule is one arrow per path.

Comment: I just noted in the second code there is no ; on each line, so that must be it.

Comment: The first and the second code fragment are the same and consequently their results are the same, exactly what you write ... What result you are expected? BTW, in fragments contains code which doing nothing (for example: `(GW) edge[bend right] node [left] {} (EGxbW);` givers the same result as `(GW) edge[bend right] (EGxbW);` ... I don't see any problem in codes or that `tikz` contain a bug, just a bit strange code fragments.

Comment: You also should be aware, that the last code lines in `\path` commands in the first two code are lost, because command `\path` is terminated already in the first line.  Sorry is not clear, what you like to achieve with your codes.

Comment: The first two fragments you can write aS `\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, every node/.style = {inner xsep=0pt} ]
\node at (1.85,-1.2) (bF) {$F$};
\node at (1.27,-1.2) (bd) {$d$};
\node at (3.6,-1.2)  (bW) {$W$};
\path   (bF.north) edge[bend right] (bd.north east) 
        (bW.north) edge[bend right] (bF.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}`. Images will have two arrows, between `F` and `d`, and between `W` and `F`.

Comment: Yes, now I see the problem, I ended the path with ;, before the second command.

Comment: Is your problem solved by this? Do you like to get an answer or can your question be closed as solved by comments?

Comment: Ah, the [->] option is being applied to each edge, not (only) the path as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

In your first two code fragments you have orphans in the last code line. Command

```
\path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}, thick]
       (GW) edge[bend right] node [left] {} (EGxbW);   % is terminated here, so
       (bW) edge[bend right] node [left] {} (ExbW);    % this line orphan: not drown
```

is terminated (by `;`) already after first code line, so the second line become orphan without instruction what to do. Consequently arrow determined in it is not drown.

So, if you extend your first code fragment to the following WME:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->, 
every node/.style = {inner xsep=0pt} ]
\node at (1.85,-1.2) (bF) {$F$};
\node at (1.27,-1.2) (bd) {$d$};
\node at (3.6,-1.2)  (bW) {$W$};
\path   (bF.north) edge[bend right] (bd.north east)  % <--- not terminated
        (bW.north) edge[bend right] (bF.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

you will get what seems to be desired result.

[image]

In comparison to your code fragment above code is simplified and shortened.